# Change performance metrics for TensorFlow 2 Object Detection API

Tags: tensorflow

Where do i find the config file?

The default metrics are based on those used in Pascal VOC evaluation.

To use the COCO object detection metrics add metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics" to the eval_config message in the config file.

To use the COCO instance segmentation metrics add metrics_set: "coco_mask_metrics" to the eval_config message in the config file.

https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a pre-trained model from the [model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md) the configuration file is the `pipeline.config` that is in every model-archive. If you are building your own network you have to write your `pipeline.config` following the guidelines.
So simply edit your `pipeline.config` adding `metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"` in the `eval_config` section for COCO, the same if you want PASCAL-VOC.